# can´t get decimal value in my MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model with a decimal value that represents the price of an event, the property has some validations

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Especifique precio evento")]
[Display(Name="Precio Evento")]
[DataType(DataType.Currency, ErrorMessage = "formato precio incorrecto")]
[RegularExpression(@"^\$?\d+(\.(\d{2}))?$", ErrorMessage = "formato precio incorrecto")]    
[Range(0, 9999999999999999.99, ErrorMessage = "precio incorrecto")]

public decimal PrecioEvento { get; set; }
```

my problem is that when the user submits the model (form's data) to the controller, if the value specified for Precioevento property is a number without point (ex: 126) the controller gets the price without any problem ... but if the user enters 126.45 then I get the value 0 in the controller, could you help and tell me what is the problem ?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the call that is made?

Comment: Can you even have regex validation on a decimal property? There may also be an issue here with international formats, many countries use commas (`,`) instead of decimal point (`.`)

Comment: Very likely, a cultureinfo problem. Your software expects a decimal number with comma as dec separator. With point, it cannot parse the string. Can you try with 123,45?

Comment: I just tried to enter a value: 123,45 but it shows me a error message, then commented out all the data annotations for the property but still gets the error message, how should I change the cultureinfo to my country for the view?

Comment: yes, was the cultureinfo, changed to my country and worked just fine